# Slower Upload speeds on ethernet than on wireless

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

**Intro:** Hi all, I recently had cat7 ethernet cables installed around my house. This new ethernet was installed to replace my ax210 wifi adapter that had around 500mb/s down and up. I connect my ethernet cable to my z370 motherboard's default ethernet nic, which is the intel I219-V. I run a speed test and get my gigabit connection of 1000 down but only 100 up.

**Specs/important details:**

1. Windows 10 version 19045
2. I219-V ethernet adapter / TP-link TX201 V1
3. Verizon fiber Gigabit home network
4. when in settings the link speed is shown as 1000/1000 and 2500/2500 respectively
5. Wireless devices (including the same computer) all have 500+mb/s upload speeds.
6. cat7 cables

**Things I have already tried:**

1. replacing my I219-V with a TP-link tx201 which is using a 2.5gbe Realtek controller
2. fiddling around with disabling power saving  settings
3. disabling ipv6 and checksum offload settings
4. attempted on a laptop with killer ethernet (updated drivers) and had the same results
5. All drivers are as up to date as possible

**Things I need to try:**

1. A different shorter ethernet cable on my router
2. Transfer speeds between computers locally in the network

Honestly right now i am thinking it is something to do with my Verizon router. I have no idea what else could be causing this. Any help would ebe greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. After eliminating all other variables, the only real option for the cause of this would be my router and modem. I went and restarted my modem and reset my router to factory defaults, and that fully solved this. I am not getting the full 1000 upload speed still (getting around 500 mb/s up), but I'm not going to split hairs over it.